# Defining Correct DataType for Nested JSON in Flink's Elasticsearch Sink (Python)

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I am working with Apache Flink and attempting to sink documents into Elasticsearch using the built-in Elasticsearch Sink. I'm having difficulty defining the correct data type for the sink to accept my documents.

My JSON documents look as follows:

```json
{
    body: {
        "foo": "bar", 
        "hello": ["world"]
    },
    doc_id: "1234"
}
```

From the documentation and my understanding, the Elasticsearch sink expects a `Types.MAP()` input. This type requires an additional type definition for both the keys and the values. In my case, all my keys are strings, but my values are a mix of strings and nested documents.

Below is my code to declare the sink. I'm using `apache-flink==1.17.1` on Python `3.10.13`.

```py
# Set up the Elasticsearch sink
elasticsearch_sink = (
    Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder()
    .set_bulk_flush_max_actions(1)
    .set_emitter(ElasticsearchEmitter.dynamic_index("name", "id"))
    .set_hosts([config["elasticsearch_endpoint"]])
    .set_connection_username(config["elasticsearch_username"])
    .set_connection_password(config["elasticsearch_password"])
    .build()
)

# Connect the stream to the sink
(
    input_stream
    .map(Entity.to_dict, Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), "<value type goes here>"))
    .sink_to(elasticsearch_sink)
    .name("Elasticsearch Sink")
)
```

I'm unsure of how to declare the correct value type for nested JSON in this context. How can I correctly define the `Types.MAP()` such that it accounts for both strings and nested documents?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Flink's Python API (PyFlink) provides several built-in types for common use cases, but for more complex nested structures, you'll need to use combinations of these types.

```
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types

list_type = Types.LIST(Types.STRING())

body_map_type = Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), Types.ROW([Types.STRING(), list_type]))

outer_map_type = Types.MAP(Types.STRING(), Types.ROW([Types.STRING(), body_map_type]))
```

Now, plug outer_map_type into your pipeline:

```
(
    input_stream
    .map(Entity.to_dict, outer_map_type)
    .sink_to(elasticsearch_sink)
    .name("Elasticsearch Sink")
)
```

If there's variability in the structure of the body map across different records, you may need to adapt this approach accordingly.